# Filters in Kibana

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-5

Need to find logs about errors in Kibana.
I can add a filter by content of a message but it's a temporary solution.
How can I make this filter constant (not just pin)?
What is the best way to do it? May be there are other solutions, not about filters in Kibana?
Thank you for help!

Comment: From my understanding, Kibana enables you to save permanently your filters, b can you be more specific? Can you add a log example?

Comment: Now I'm searching like this: [printscreen](http://joxi.net/Dr8MyG7TkyxqGm)
Yes, I know I can save my search history and use it again. 
Maybe there is more rational way to do this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this also from the **Discover** tab:

[image]

You need to use a **logstash filter** , this enables you split your entire log message into elements (see picture 2), that way you can easily read your messages and it lets you focus on the important attributes.